# Adding Double type values

Tags: java

I have two values (`Double` type).
`a = 1`
`b = 1.11`
When I add them together the result is `2.1100000000000003`. Why?
There is no problem with `1 + 1.1`

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: This is a good question but there is a duplicate: do study it carefully. Note that Java uses IEEE754 floating point.